# Is there a batteries-included server framework for graphQL api?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I enjoy using loopback to quickly build a REST api, with a fair amount of scaffolding. All I need to do is define my data, write any custom validations, and add any other server-side logic. For simple requirements, you can have a RESTful API in minutes. What about GraphQL?

Loopback doesn't support GraphQL. A quick websearch shows a few grapql servers like express-graphql. Is there a more batteries-included option? I don't want to write a web-server. I want a framework, but I can't find such.

I just want a functioning and stable data-abstraction layer, access control, a graphQL interface, and a solid way to connect all of these reliably. Is there a solution available already?

I would prefer a solution using either nodejs or python

It may help you to know that I have just discovered GraphQL. So maybe my question shows a fundamental misunderstanding of the topic, maybe I'm ignoring something obvious. If so, enlighten me.

Comment: I in no way am associated with these guys, but you might wanna check out [Reindex](https://www.reindex.io/). Just feed it your desired schema, and you'll have access to a generated GraphiQL.

Comment: I'm looking for my own solution, something I can host locally. It is certainly interesting, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does Apollo server come closer to what you're looking for? https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-server/blob/master/README.md

> express-graphql's main goal is to be a minimal reference implementation, whereas Apollo Server's goal is to be a complete production-ready GraphQL server.

Comment: It isn't exactly batteries-included, but I think it serves my purposes pretty well. It's clear that graphQL is very new and given that short timeframe Apollo looks like a relatively mature solution. Thanks

Comment: Maybe a more 'batteries-included' answer will come along, if not, please consider marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/Tallyb/loopback-graphql (disclosure: I am the author)